# Headset too stiff

Tags: headset

yesterday I noticed that I had some play in my headset.

So I loosen the stem bolts and tighten the preload just to eliminate the play, but then the headset becomes too stiff.

So I can't avoid play without having the steering a little too stiff (wheel won't move freely)

Could this be worn or dirty bearings ?

Also there is a lot of creaking coming from the headset

thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the website! it looks like the headset is due for an overhaul. Without a more detailed insight into what is happening inside it, there is no reliable way for anyone who has not even seen it, to guess what's going on.

Comment: Can you completely remove the fork and see if the bearings run smoothly if you turn them by hand (assuming you have sealed cartridge bearings)? If you have open ball bearings you could inspect and grease them.